# Ocamllex Syntactical issue

Tags: ocaml, lex, ocamllex

```
{ }
rule translate = parse
| "current_directory" { print_string (Sys.getcwd ()) }
| _ as c { print_char c }
| eof { exit 0 }
{
let main () =
let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
while true do
translate lexbuf
done
let _ = Printexc.print main ()
}
```

Can someone please explain me how the main function works? I have understood the regexp part, and am able to get a sense of the main function, but not the exact meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The `main` function looks like this:

```
let main () =
  let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
  while true do
    translate lexbuf
  done
```

It creates a lexbuf using stdin as its source, then calls `translate` repeatedly using this lexbuf. The type of `translate` is `Lexing.lexbuf -> unit`. It expects a lexbuf, looks for one token, and executes the associated rule. You define a rule for `eof` that causes the program to exit, which terminates the `while`.

The next line actually runs the `main` function:

```
let _ = Printexc.print main ()
```

What this does is call `main`, passing it `()`. If an exception is raised during execution, `Printexc.print` will print out a description of it. Since no exception is raised in the test, eventually you reach the end of file and the `eof` rule causes the program to exit.